# A be a $3\times3$ real valued matrix such that $A^{3}=I$ but $A \neq I$ .Then trace(A)=?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was thinking about the following problem:

Let A be a $3\times3$ real valued matrix such that $A^{3}=I$ but $A \neq I$ . Then trace of A must be

> (a)0,
>   (b)1,
>   (c)-1,
>   (d)3.

My attempts: I take A to be $$\begin{pmatrix}
x &0  &0 \\ 
 0& x &0 \\ 
 0&0  & x
\end{pmatrix}.$$ 
Now we see $A^{3}=I$ gives $x^{3}=1$ which gives $x=1,w,w^{2}$ where $w$ being the cube root of unity. Thus we see that trace of A is $1+w+w^{2}=0$. So ,i think that (a) is the  right choice.Am i going in the right direction? Please give your valuable opinion. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Your argument doesn't work in general. For instance, the diagonal matrix with entries $1, \omega, \omega$ also satisfies $A^3=I$, but its trace is non-zero. You have to use the fact that $A$ is a real matrix.

Comment: Hint 1: The Trace of a matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues. Hint 2: If $A$ is a real matrix, then its complex eigenvalues come in pairs $(a+bi, a-bi)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $A^3=I \Longrightarrow$  the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $x^3-1$. Thus the eigenvalues of $A$ are in $\{1,\omega,\omega^2\}$ ($\omega$ is a primitive third root of unity). 
Since $A$ is real if $\omega$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $\bar{\omega}=\omega^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. The same if $\omega^2$ is an eigenvalue.
 Therefore we have only two possibilities for the eigenvalues of $A$. Either $1,1,1$ or $1,\omega,\omega^2$. If the eigenvalues are $1,1,1$ then the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $x-1$, thus $A=I$ (why?). 
Therefore if $A\neq I$ the eigenvalues are $1,\omega,\omega^2$ and the trace is $0$.

Comment: 1) This is a homework problem so don't just give the solutions away; 2) your answer is essentially the same as mine.

Comment: @BenjaLim It seems that he knows that if $1,\omega,\omega^2$ are the eigenvalues then the trace is $0$. Indeed your answer is the same as mine...

Comment: And both your answers are the same as my comment :-)

Comment: @TonyK: Yes they are :-)