# find eigenvalues of A whenA is $3\times3$ real valued matrix such that $A^{3}=I$ but $A \neq I$

Tags: linear-algebra

I was thinking about the following problem:

Let A be a $3\times3$ real valued matrix such that $A^{3}=I$ but $A \neq I$ . Then trace of A must be

> (a)0,
>   (b)1,
>   (c)-1,
>   (d)3

I have went through the answer which says that $x=1,w,w^{2}$ are it's eigenvalues and hence $trace(A)=0$([A be a $3\times3$ real valued matrix such that $A^{3}=I$ but $A \neq I$ .Then trace(A)=?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256168/a-be-a-3-times3-real-valued-matrix-such-that-a3-i-but-a-neq-i-then-tr)).  But, since we have considered matrix over real field ,how can i have complex eigenvalues at all.

my confusion arises from an example in hoffman's text which is

$ A =$$
   \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & -1 \\
    1 &0   \\
   \end{pmatrix}
$$
$

then,$ch_A(x)$=$x^2+1$,which has no real roots,so,A has no eigenvalues.So, how in above problem we have complex eigenvalues??

thanks for your time in advance...

Comment: Your example has no **real** eigenvalues. However every matrix with real entries has complex eigenvalues. This follows from fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: @sahiba arora:then,how to find eigenvalues of the problem,i see that $ch_A(x)=x^3-1$ but how do we get eigenvalues from here??because now this equation has only 1 as real root and since matrix is considered over $\Bbb R$ so we cannot solve the equation for complex roots...so how

Comment: When the matrix is considered over $\mathbb{R}$, it means the entries are real. The matrix definitely has complex eigenvalues. It does not mean you ignore the complex eigenvalues.

Comment: @sahiba arora:this means that real matrix can have complex eigenvalues...but roots of characteristic polynomial of this real matrix gives us only the roots which belong to field $\Bbb R$.for finding complex roots,we have to think in other way...like you did in your answer

Comment: Real matrix **always** has complex eigenvalues. Eigenvalues are just roots of characteristic polynomial. The characteristic polynomial will give you all roots including the ones that don't belong to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @sahiba arora:then as given in example above,why does hoffman book saya that A has no eigenvalues(I think that he says it because in definition of eigenvalue itself ,eigenvalues are considered only over the field of matrix)

Comment: I checked the book. Prior to the example, Hoffman defines characteristic value over the field $\mathbb{F}$. In the example he is trying to illustrate that eigenvalues may not exist in the field $\mathbb{F}$. However, the roots will certainly exist in the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}$ which in our case is $\mathbb{C}$. However if you are working on some problem related to eigenvalues you certainly need all the eigenvalues of the matrix to give you the information you need.

Comment: @sahiba arora:ok...thanks a lot  for your clarification...but, i strictly think if that is the case then $\lambda\in\Bbb F$ should not be mentioned in definition...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to see this:  if the matrix $A$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$, then the eigenvalues of $A^3$ are $\lambda_1^3, \lambda_2^3$, and $\lambda_3^3$.  But the eigenvalues of $A^3 = I$ are all 1 (with three-fold degeneracy), which means that $\lambda_1^3 = \lambda_2^3 = \lambda_3^3 = 1$.  Thus, the $\lambda_i$ are all cube roots of unity.  Moreover, since $A$ is real-valued, the trace of $A$ is real, and $\mathrm{tr}(A) = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3$.  There are only two ways for this quantity to be real:  either $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \lambda_3 = 1$ (which implies $A = I$, a contradiction) or $\lambda_1 = 1$, $\lambda_2 = e^{2 \pi i/3}$, and $\lambda_3 = e^{4 \pi i/3}$.  In the latter case, $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ch_A(x) = x^3 -1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$$

Therefore roots of $ch_A(x)$ are $1$, $\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}$ and $\frac{-1-\sqrt{3}i}{2}$

Let $\omega =\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}$. Then $\omega ^2 = \frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}$.

Clearly, $\omega$ satisfies $1+ \omega + \omega^2 =0$.

Comment: $(-1 \pm \sqrt{3} i)/2$, not $(-1 \pm 3 i)/2$, surely?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Thanks for pointing that out. I missed the square root. Have corrected it now :)

Comment: Why $ch_A(x) = x^3-1$? It's correct, but that's the gist of the problem.

Comment: @QuangHoang If you read the comments, OP only had trouble with roots of $ch_A(x)$. That is the reason I didn't see the need to elaborate on that.