# Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $A^2=-I$. Find all eigenvalues of A.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The conclusion I got was A has no real eigenvalues.

Can anyone tell me if it's right or what are these eigenvalues?

Comment: You're right: the eigenvalues are not in $\mathbb R$. However, $A$ does have complex eigenvalues; see greedoid's answer. It is actually often the case that a real $n\times n$ matrix will have complex eigenvalues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $Av = \lambda v$ then $$ A^2v = A( \lambda v) =  \lambda (Av) = \lambda^2v $$

But $$A^2v = -Iv=-v \implies ( \lambda^2+1)v = 0$$

So $ \lambda =\pm i$.

Comment: I do this. If $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ there is no problem of the eigenvalues being in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: No, ther is no problem with $\mathbb{C}$. It is the same as if you have a polynomial with real coeficients. It can have comples roots.

Comment: You can see something similary here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2314703/find-eigenvalues-of-a-whena-is-3-times3-real-valued-matrix-such-that-a3-i?rq=1

Comment: Yes, there is a problem. Look at the case $n=3$.